# Download file from DB with ajax call MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm trying to implement file download functionality thru ajax call in MVC.
After calling of controller method i always have a "parseerror", can somebody explain me why?

my ajax:

```
tab.on("click", ".FileDownload", function (e) {

    //$('#uploadStatus').html("ok");
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = tr.data("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/File/FileDownload",
        //contentType: false,
        //processData: false,
        //dataType: "json",
        data: { fileId: id },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#uploadStatus').html("ok");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
    });

});
```

and controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileResult FileDownload(int? fileId)
    {

        FileDBEntities db = new FileDBEntities();
        tblFile file = db.tblFiles.ToList().Find(p => p.id == fileId.Value);
        return File(file.Data, file.ContentType, file.Name);
    }
```

with simple download link in razor it works, but not with ajax.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simple use

```
tab.on("click", ".FileDownload", function (e) {

    //$('#uploadStatus').html("ok");
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = tr.data("id");

    window.location = window.location.origin + '/File/FileDownload?fileId=' + id;

});

[HttpGet]
    public FileResult FileDownload(int? fileId)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was easyer than I've thought XD